# Sql server instance id is required but don't have other instances installed

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to install SQL Server 2014. In the setup, I have clicked on Default instance (rather than Named instance) and want to make the Instance ID empty. My main goal is to be able to connect to SQL Server using just `.\`. But I am being forced to input an Instance ID even though I am pretty sure I shouldn't need to put one in if there are no other instances installed (which there are not). I am using this guide here and am at step 14 which shows screenshots of what I am seeing:

http://www.exactsoftware.com/docs/DocView.aspx?DocumentID=%7Ba6937c87-21f5-46db-a166-ba84e83037e3%7D

Now it could be that I have misunderstood, and Instance ID is always required, but if not, do you know why I am forced to put one in?

Please note, that it automatically sets an InstanceID of MSSQLSERVER.

Also, I currently have the following things installed:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Transact-SQL Compiler Service
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Transact-SQL Compiler ScriptDom
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 T-SQL Language Service
Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 x64 ENU
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - enu (14.0.50616.0)
Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types
```

Do I maybe need to uninstall any of these?

Comment: Hi. Open SQL Studio. Your username to login will be instance\username. Use that instance.

Comment: @KapilaRamji that is incorrect. @Alan Schapire, after you install that (with that instance name) you should be able to connect to the default instance (just a `.`) - see CPMunich post below.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid As answered below by CPMunich, every install has a default instance name.

Comment: I was referring to 'your username will be instance\username' as being incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even a default instance has a name, in this case MSSQLSERVER.
This is because the directory structure of the SQL-Server installation, the registry entries and service names reflect the name of the instance. For a default instance there is no need to specify the name of the instance to make a connection.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143531.aspx